# create setting option in admin panel of a plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a plugin , for that I want to create a menu item in admin section. It will open a page and I want to add the options into the database using a form.

If anyone has code for it please provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

There are multiple code examples under ["See it all together"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages#See_It_All_Together)

The below example uses the new Settings API to create and save plugin options:

```
<?php
// create custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_cool_plugin_create_menu');

function my_cool_plugin_create_menu() {
    //create new top-level menu     
    add_menu_page(
        'My Cool Plugin Settings',
        'Cool Settings',
        'administrator',
        __FILE__,
        'my_cool_plugin_settings_page',
        plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__)
    );  
    //call register settings function   
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_cool_plugin_settings' );
}

function register_my_cool_plugin_settings() {   
    //register our settings     
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );     
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );   
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'option_etc' ); 
}

function my_cool_plugin_settings_page() { ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Your Plugin Name</h1>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('new_option_name') ); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Some Other Option</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('some_other_option') ); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Options, Etc.</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('option_etc') ); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks. I'm having some trouble formatting the most relevant part on my mobile device. Will edit further later.